# Problema con modal y consulta php

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap

Mi duda es la siguiente 
Tengo este condigo donde consulto información y creo un arreglo, cuando le doy click a un botón de detalle obtengo un archivo post que me trae el valor de idweb de esa fila, ademas de abrir un modal que debería contener los datos de la consulta pero cuando realizo este proceso obtengo el modal sin datos

```
    <?php 
    $tour="";
    $adultos="";
    $ninos="";
    $fecha="";
    $hora="";
    $hotel="";
    $observaciones="";
    $precio="";
    $idweb="0";
    if (isset($_POST["idweb2"])) //esta es una variable que obtengo cuando se le 
    da click a una fila de tabla {
    $idweb = $_POST["idweb2"];
    require_once("../_clases/class-mysqli.php");
    $instance = new Conexion();
    $conexion = $instance->Conect();

     $consulta='SELECT * FROM tbldetalle WHERE idweb='.$idweb.'';
     $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

      while($datos=$resultado->fetch_array()){

             $tour2=$datos["tour"];
             $adultos2=$datos["adultos"];
             $ninos2=$datos["ninos"]; 
             $fecha2=$datos["fecha"];
             $hora2=$datos["hora"];
             $hotel2=$datos["hotel"];
             $observaciones2=$datos["observaciones"];
             $precio2=$datos["precio"];


          }

          }    


         echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){ 
         $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
         });</script>

            <div class='modal fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' 
             aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'>
            <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
            <div class='modal-header'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria- 
            label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class='modal-title text-center'  id='myModalLabel'>Detalle de la 
            Reserva</h4>
            </div>
           <div class='modal-body'>

            <div class='table-responsive'>  
             <table class='table table-bordered'>
                <tr>  
                     <td  style='background-color:var(--dark-primary- 
              color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Tour</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%''>".$tour2."</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary- 
              color);color:white' width='30%''><label>Adultos</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%''>".$adultos2."</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary-color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Niños</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%'>".$ninos2."</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary-color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Fecha operación</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%'>".$fecha2."</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary-color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Hora</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%'>".$hora2."</td>  
                </tr>  

                <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary-color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Hotel</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%'>".$hotel2."</td>  
                </tr>  

                 <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary-color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Observaciones</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%'>".$observaciones2."</td>  
                </tr>  
                 <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary-color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Precio</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%'>".$precio2."</td>  
                </tr>  

           </table>  
      </div>  

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        ";   


        ?>
```

disculpen que saliera así pero es la primera vez que inserto código
muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Probaste a imprimir los datos con echo? Así vez si realmente se está guardando la consulta en las variables

Comment: al parecer no esta entrando el post con esa llave no existe, te recomiendo que imprimas el post antes de hacer la condicional para ver que le mandas o que llave le estas mandando , pon un var_dum($_POST); exit(); y comenta el resultado

Comment: @AndySamuelAlvarado así es hago echo al final del modal pero no me imprime el valor sin embargo en la parte de network para checar las peticiones xhr en en el post que mando si recibo cada uno de los datos, muchas gracias

Comment: @JoseLuisEsparza realice el var dump y optengo string(1) "5" y va variando segun la fila que seleccione. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que poner el código de salida dentro del **while**, actualmente tu código recorre el bucle y luego pinta el html, al salir del bucle no debe tener datos.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
    <?php 
    $tour="";
    $adultos="";
    $ninos="";
    $fecha="";
    $hora="";
    $hotel="";
    $observaciones="";
    $precio="";
    $idweb="0";
    if (isset($_POST["idweb2"])) //esta es una variable que obtengo cuando se le 
    da click a una fila de tabla {
    $idweb = $_POST["idweb2"];
    require_once("../_clases/class-mysqli.php");
    $instance = new Conexion();
    $conexion = $instance->Conect();

     $consulta='SELECT * FROM tbldetalle WHERE idweb='.$idweb.'';
     $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

      while($datos=$resultado->fetch_array()){

             $tour2=$datos["tour"];
             $adultos2=$datos["adultos"];
             $ninos2=$datos["ninos"]; 
             $fecha2=$datos["fecha"];
             $hora2=$datos["hora"];
             $hotel2=$datos["hotel"];
             $observaciones2=$datos["observaciones"];
             $precio2=$datos["precio"];
echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){ 
         $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
         });</script>

            <div class='modal fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' 
             aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'>
            <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
            <div class='modal-header'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria- 
            label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class='modal-title text-center'  id='myModalLabel'>Detalle de la 
            Reserva</h4>
            </div>
           <div class='modal-body'>

            <div class='table-responsive'>  
             <table class='table table-bordered'>
                <tr>  
                     <td  style='background-color:var(--dark-primary- 
              color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Tour</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%''>".$tour2."</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary- 
              color);color:white' width='30%''><label>Adultos</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%''>".$adultos2."</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary-color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Niños</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%'>".$ninos2."</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary-color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Fecha operación</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%'>".$fecha2."</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary-color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Hora</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%'>".$hora2."</td>  
                </tr>  

                <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary-color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Hotel</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%'>".$hotel2."</td>  
                </tr>  

                 <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary-color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Observaciones</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%'>".$observaciones2."</td>  
                </tr>  
                 <tr>  
                     <td style='background-color:var(--dark-primary-color);color:white' width='30%'><label>Precio</label></td>  
                     <td width='70%'>".$precio2."</td>  
                </tr>  

           </table>  
      </div>  

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        ";   

          }

          }    



        ?>
```

Comment: Lucas D.A.W realice ese cambio como sugeriste pero ahora no me abre el modal, muchas gracias por el aporte

Comment: prueba concatenando el id de cada registro a su modal correspondiente, es decir, hacer algo com0: $('#myModal-". $datos["idweb"]."').modal('show'); y en el modal agregar: <div class='modal fade' id='myModal-".$datos["idweb"]."' tabindex='-1' role='dialog'

Comment: @LuiscYm el modal si cambia su idweb tanto en en el scritp como en el div pero ahora no se abre el modal. Saludos cordiales y Gracias por el aporte